# How do I manage to create a vector class in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I was introduced to pointers, I quite get it. but I don't know how to store variables in the vector class using pointers.

Here is what I got from my understanding but how should I complete it?

```
class Vector{
    int size;       
    int* element; 

    public:
    vector(int x); 

    int size() const { return size }
};
```

Comment: Think about how you will implement your constructor, copy constructor and destructor.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyFavouriteClass>>`?

Comment: You can easily search around for examples of this. Or ask your teacher/professor/TA for help (that's what they're there for).

Comment: You need to dynamically allocate memory for your elements.  All you have is an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to define a value that stores the current size - (number of elements inside the vector) - to be able to add values at the end of the vector.

```
int curr_vec_size;
```

also, the actual size of the vector should be saved in a variable to check every time you add a value that allocated memory is not full

```
int memory_size;
```

second, you need to allocate memory dynamically by using "new" in the constructor

```
    vector(int size)
{
    element = new int[size];        //allocating memory (array of integers)
    memory_size= size;              //size of allocated memory
    curr_vec_size= 0;               //no values in the vector 
}
```

then you can make a method that takes an int value and adds it to the dynamic array.

```
    void add_value(int passed_val)
{
    if(curr_vec_size < memory_size)
    {
        element[curr_vec_size]=passed_val;    //adding the value in the vector
        curr_vec_size ++;                     //because you have added a new value
    }
    else 
        cout<<"vector is full \n";
}
```

Finally, don't forget to delete the memory you've allocated by using destructors that deletes the pointer to this allocated memory.

```
vector()
{
   delete[] element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete what you started, you simply need to use `new[]` operator to allocate memory to store your `int` values:

```
vector(int x)
{
    size = x;
    element = new int[size]; // this allocates an array of int with a size of "size"
}
```

Then, you can use `element[i]` to access i's element of your array.

You'll later need (it's a must) to release allocatd memory to prevent memory leak by implementing a destructor:

```
~vector()
{
    delete [] element;
}
```

Note that you should (must) also also follow at least the rule of 3 to have you vector be copiable.

Comment: Addendum: don't forget the Rule of Three. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Click the link and find out!

Comment: @user4581301: I mentioned that ;-)

Comment: So you did. My apologies.